# Can't ping ip's or hostnames on fresh CentOS 6.2 install

Tags: linux, centos, centos-6

I just installed CentOS 6.2 on a box using ipmi and have tried setting up the network with no luck.

I've got a 66.x.x.56/29 allocation of ip addresses on vlan (66.x.x.56 to 66.x.x.63), so I have set up 5 ips on one of the nics. 66.x.x.57 is the gateway.

My problem is I can ping any of the 5 ip's on eth1 and get a response, but I cannot ping the gateway or any other ip/hostname. Basically, no outside connections..

/etc/resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

/etc/sysconfig/network

```
NETWORKING=yes
NETWORKING_IPV6=no
HOSTNAME=hostname.mydomain.com
GATEWAY=66.x.x.57
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1

```
DEVICE="eth1"
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=66.x.x.58
NETMASK=255.255.255.248
ONBOOT=yes
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1:1

```
DEVICE="eth1:1"
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=66.x.x.59
NETMASK=255.255.255.248
ONBOOT=yes
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1:2

```
DEVICE="eth1:2"
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=66.x.x.60
NETMASK=255.255.255.248
ONBOOT=yes
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1:3

```
DEVICE="eth1:3"
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=66.x.x.61
NETMASK=255.255.255.248
ONBOOT=yes
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1:4

```
DEVICE="eth1:4"
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=66.x.x.62
NETMASK=255.255.255.248
ONBOOT=yes
```

route -n

```
Dest           Gateway       Genmask            Flags   Metric   Ref  Use   Iface
66.x.x.56      0.0.0.0       255.255.255.248    U       0        0    0     eth1
169.254.0.0    0.0.0.0       255.255.0.0        U       1003     0    0     eth1
0.0.0.0        66.x.x.57     0.0.0.0            UG      0        0    0     eth1
```

Please let me know if I left anything out.I included anything that I thought was necessary! Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you have HWADDR set at all?

Comment: What happens when you try to ping the gateway?

Comment: @grawity HWADDR was just there whenever I first edited the file, and then I just carried it over to the aliases since it complained about wrong HWADDR whenever I tried removing it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It tries to ping, then it shows "Destination Host Unreachable"

Answer (score 2):

`.56` is the subnet address. You can't use it as a host address. When you try to reach the gateway, the source IP address is the subnet address, leaving the gateway baffled as to how to respond. By assigning `.56` to the physical interface, you have made it the default source IP address.

Comment: Ah yea, that was dumb. I fixed that and modified my eth1 and alias. I still can't get a response from the gateway with ping.

Comment: What is the source address of the `ping` packets now? Did you wait for ARP to expire?

Comment: The source address is now the .58 address. arp -na shows incomplete, and arping never gets a response